# Checking whether a program exists

Tags: linux, bash, perl

In the middle of my perl script I want to execute a bash command. The script takes a long time, so at the beginning of the script I want to see if the command exists. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1882328/3280538) says to just try and run it and [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script) suggests some bash commands to test if the program exists.

Is the latter option the best solution? Are there any better ways to do this check in perl?

Comment: Are you going to call the command immediately anyway?

Comment: @ikegami no, its halfway through the script

Comment: Then just running it makes no sense.

Comment: Do you have the full path to the external program?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I'm checking to see if its installed, so I guess the /usr/bin/ directory.

Comment: If you *know* it will be in /usr/bin and nowhere else, you can test for the existence of the full path to the program like syck showed. If you're relying on the shell to find the program somewhere in your PATH, that approach won't work; then again, you probably shouldn't be relying on PATH anyway.

Comment: Do you mean a *bash command* (a built-in that is part of the shell, like `echo`) or do you need to check for the existence of an executable file? Note that, unless your command line contains shell metacharacters, perl will execute it directly without involving the shell

Comment: What is *halfway through the script*? Is it 500μs, 30 minutes, or a couple days? And is it preceded by stuff that does things that are difficult to roll back?

Comment: This is either a duplicate of one of the linked questions, or it's opinion-based. Just try them both and see which one works better for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me a better check is to run the program at the beginning of the script (with `-V` say).

I'd use the same invocation as you use to run the job later (via shell or not, via `execvp`). Once at it, make sure to see whether it threw errors. This is also discussed in your link but I would in fact get the output back (*not* send it away) and check that. This is the surest way to see whether the thing actually runs out of your program and whether it is what you expect it to be.

Checking for the executable with `-x` (if you know the path) is useful, too, but it only tells you that a file with a given name is there and that it is executable.

The system's `which` seems to be beset with critism for its possible (mis)behavior, it may or may not be a shell-builtin (which complicates how exactly to use it), is an external utility, and its exact behavior is system dependent. The module `File::Which` pointed out in [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin)'s answer would be better -- if it is indeed better than `which`. (What it may well be, I just don't know.)

---

*Note*.  I am not sure what "*bash command*" means: a bash shell built-in, or the fact that you use bash when on terminal? Perl's `qx` and `system` use the `sh` shell, not `bash` (if they invoke the shell, which depends on how you use them). While `sh` is mostly a link, and often to `bash`, it may not be and there are differences, and you cannot rely on your shell configuration.

Can also actually run a shell, `qx(/path/bash -c 'cmd args')`, if you must. Mind the quotes. You may need to play with it to find the exact syntax on your system. See [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374082/perl-backticks-use-bash-instead-of-sh) and links.

Answer (score 4):

My best guess is that you want to check for existence of an executable file that you want to run using `system` or `qx//`

But if you want your command line to behave the same way as the shell, then you can probably use [`File::Which`](http://metacpan.org/module/File::Which)

Comment: You can't assume which is installed

Answer (score 3):

What if we assume that we don't know the command's location?
This means that syck's answer won't work, and zdim's answer is incomplete.

Try this function in perl:

```
sub check_exists_command { 
    my $check = `sh -c 'command -v $_[0]'`; 
    return $check;
}
# two examples 
check_exists_command 'pgrep' or die "$0 requires pgrep";
check_exists_command 'readlink' or die "$0 requires readlink";
```

I just tested it, because I just wrote it.

Comment: Oh that's another interesting option! Just as a personal style note, I think I'd rather use `qx//` over backticks as I find that a bit easier to read!

Comment: This is vulnerable to command injection and therefore extremely unsafe. If you have to use this approach, never ever pass untrusted data to `check_exists_command`.

Answer (score 2):

With perl, you can test files for existence, readability, executability etc., take a look [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html).

Therefore just use

```
executeBashStuff() if -x $filename;
```

or `stat` it:

```
stat($filename);
executeBashStuff() if -x _;
```

Comment: The `open` is superfluous. Just `execute_bash_stuff() if -x $filename`. You would make a lot of people who are familiar with Perl happy if you kept to `snake_case` variables. Ultimately I'm not sure that this answers what the OP is asking

Comment: No need to comment on a fix